# How to reuse the mysql database node in node red?

Tags: node.js, iot, node-red

Currently i am working on node red project. In that i want to update three different table from node red dashboard based on user inputs.

So i want to access database more than 20 times. So i am using a database node from node-red-node-mysql palette in all 20 place. Now it is working fine. but if i  want to configure an another database then i need to change in all nodes in my flows. In real time also it is difficult. As just an idea, Is it possible to use only one database node for all my flows and split the output of the database to different nodes based on the message? If yes please give me some example.

Comment: Based on this information you provided, this is just a configuration work inside your application.

Comment: Hey Thanks for comment. Yes its configuration work. But i am worrying about using database node many time wont create any problem? Is there any way to configure is one place? @VedranMaricevic.

Comment: And again it is up to you. Don't know about the Red (just found about it in your post. Looks good). Make a connection to DB, in one place. Have it exposed to your API's. And always make sure it is closed after usage. That should be general approach.

Comment: Its ok @VedranMaricevic. without knowledge of node red, it is difficult to understand my point. But Close after usage will take care by that palette i believe.

Comment: The `mysql` node (like most node-red nodes) is designed to be reused -- the only input you really need is a sql statement passed in on the `msg.topic` property. So you can wire many flows into a single `mysql` node, if that makes sense in your flows. If you update your question to include your flows exported as JSON, we can give you some more concrete examples of ways to simplify the flow...